# Smooth update google maps overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My problem is I need to have a very custom marker to show the users location and I'm using [this](https://humaan.com/blog/custom-html-markers-google-maps/) method to create. However my marker isn't stationary and I need to redraw it once user location changes.

Currently I've tried removing the overlay from the map using `OverLayName.setMap(null);` and removing the dom element with javascript, but both ways I get a flicking effect of the marker being removed from the map and added, which isn't smooth.

Is there a way to move the overlay on the map without it being removed and being drawn again ? Or maybe there is a way to create a smooth redraw visualization with css ?

Cheers guys.